# Spring service save method and start thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

I want to save an entity over a Rest endpoint and return the DTO rightaway. After that, I want to append some data that takes some time to the entity and save it.

Thats what my question really boils down to, **is there a preferred way to do this in a Spring Boot project?**

Just for reference, I came up with two ways, which both are not fully functioning:

**Approach 1 - Async**

```
@Service
public class EntityServiceImpl implements EntityService {

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Entity save(Entity entity) {
        Entity saved = repository.save(entity);
        asyncCalculation(entity.getId());
        return saved;
    }

    @Async
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void asyncCalculation(Long id) {
        Entity entity = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow( () ... );
        entity.setData(longCalculation(entity));
        repository.save(entity);
    }


}
```

I have `@EnableAsync` on one of my `@Configuration` classes and additionally a Bean within said configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAsync
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor asyncExecutor() {
        // setting a breakpoint here gets this called, so this should mean the configuration
        // gets triggered?
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5); 
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

However, this does not run async, it just runs sequentially. Is there some configuration missing? Also I'm not quite sure about transactions here, because the commit in the save() method does not appear until after the return, so I don't fully understand why this even works because I would access the entity before it was really saved to the database.

**Approach 2 - Threads and own Transactionmanagement**

Same Service class as before, just:

```
        @Autowired
        private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

        @Override
        // no transactional
        public Entity save(Entity entity) {
            TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);

            Entity savedEntity = transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
                return repository.save(entity)
            });
            // now it is commited
            
            new Thread(() -> {
                asyncCalculation(savedEntity.getId());
            }).start();

            return savedEntity ;
        }

        // no @Async
        @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
        private void asyncCalculation(Long id) {
            Entity entity = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow( () ... );
            entity.setData(longCalculation(entity));
            // longCalculation triggers LazyInitializations
            repository.save(entity);
        }
```

The `longCalculation()` triggers initializations of the entity, but although I annotated the method with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` I get a `LazyInitializationException`: could not initialize proxy [org.project.domain.SubEntity#767204] - no Session. The `SubEntity` is connected to `Entity` via `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

Comment: AOP (which is used for `@Async` and `@Transactional`) doesn't work for internal method calls nor wold it work for `private` methods. Move it to a different class so it isn't an internal invocation anymore.

Comment: Thank you for that insight! Now it is executing like I expected. But I cannot load the entity within the async method, because it is not saved at this point. So I guess I need a mix of Solution 1 and 2? So handle transactionmanagement myself and then add the threads with @Async? 

I just thought maybe there is something like @RunAfterAsync(). It would work with an Aspect and a Pointcut I guess, but it seems overkill because I just need that code for this method, it's not a "cross cutting concern".

Comment: You can use an `@TransactionalEventListener` instead. Fire an event inside your method (using the Spring application events) and make the `@TransactionalEventListener` execute after the commit (one of the phases that is available).

Comment: What an elegant and easy solution! Thank you. Do you want to past that as an answer? Otherwise I'll just update my code and add that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proxy based AOP (which is the default for Spring and used for `@Async` and `@Transactional`) won't work with internal method calls. Simply due to the fact that you are inside the object.

You can solve this in a couple of ways:

1. by moving this method to another class and call it
2. by doing a self invocation, meaning injecting an instance of the service into itself and call the method on it (leading to an external invocation).
3. For this particular case: Create an `@TransactionalEventListener` which listens to an event and bind it to the `AFTER_COMMIT` phase (that way the data is present).

```java
public record MyEvent(long id) { }
```

```java
public class MyEventListener {

  @Async
  @TransactionalEventListener(phase = AFTER_COMMIT)
  public void calculation(MyEvent evt) {
    Entity entity = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow( () ... );
    entity.setData(longCalculation(entity));
    // longCalculation triggers LazyInitializations
    repository.save(entity);
  }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class EntityServiceImpl implements EntityService {

    private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    public EntityServiceImpl(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
      this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Entity save(Entity entity) {
        Entity saved = repository.save(entity);
        publisher.publishEvent(new MyEvent(entity.getId());
        return saved;
    }
}
```